# What are some good papers that discuss Tufte's 'data density index' and 'data-to-ink ratio' in data visualisation?

Tags: visualization

I've found a number of resources that mention Tufte's 'data density index' and 'data-to-ink ratio' when considering the analysis of particular visualisations and visualisation techniques, but I am yet to come across any papers that actually critique the measures themselves.

Are there critiques of these principles available?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are critcism's of Tuft's principles.  Some examples:

[*Sometimes We Must Raise Our Voices*](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/sometimes_we_must_raise_our_voices.pdf), Stephen Few, Perceptual Edge

> Even after many years of working in the field of data visualization, which has involved a great deal of experience and study that has expanded my expertise into many areas that Tufte hasn’t specifically addressed, I have only on rare occasions discovered reasons to disagree with any of his principles. The topic that I’m addressing in this article, however, deals with one of those rare disagreements.

[*Minimalism in information visualization: attitudes towards maximizing the data-ink ratio*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1362587)

From the abstract:

> People did not like Tufte's minimalist design of bar-graphs; they seem to prefer "chartjunk" instead.